# Finding a 0 centered Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Stuck on trying to find the Laurent series for $$\frac{e^z -1}{z^2}$$ centered at $z_0 = 0$. Still new to Laurent series, so not entirely sure how to get it. I know the Taylor series for $e^z$ but don't know how to deal with the -1 like that.

Any guidance would be very helpful

Comment: What is the first term of the Taylor series for $e^z$?

Answer (score 2):

So you know the series for $e^z$. Which is to say, you're familiar with
$$
e^z = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}2 + \frac{z^3}6 + \frac{z^4}{24} + \cdots
$$
Now, subtracting $1$ means just that: subtract $1$. It's as easy as can be.
$$
e^z - 1 = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}2 + \frac{z^3}6 + \frac{z^4}{24} + \cdots - 1\\
= z + \frac{z^2}2 + \frac{z^3}6 + \frac{z^4}{24} + \cdots
$$
Finally, dividing by $z^2$ is similarly straight-forward:
$$
\frac{e^z - 1}{z^2} = \frac{z + \frac{z^2}2 + \frac{z^3}6 + \frac{z^4}{24} + \cdots}{z^2}\\
= \frac1z + \frac12 + \frac z6 + \frac{z^2}{24} + \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^z$ has Taylor series, about z= 0, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}= 1+ z+ \frac{z^2}{2}+ \frac{z^3}{3!}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$.    So $e^z- 1$ has series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}= z+ \frac{z^2}{2}+ \frac{z^3}{3!}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$. Then $\frac{e^z-1}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z}+ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{z}{3!}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n-2}}{n!}$.